# Is it possible to run OnEnable() when a diferent object is enabled?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanted to know if it's possible to make the onEnable() function work if a child object is enabled instead of the object containing the script. In this case I've made a Menu with a main script in the parent object, and some scripts to detect onEnable() on the child objects that interact with the main one, so I would like to make it simple by using only the script in the parent object. Is this an option or do I have to stick to using multiple scripts for this?

This would be one of the secondary scripts (MenuOpenUpdate). The bool that has it's value changed in both of the voids will interact with the main script.

```
void Start(){
public static bool MenuOpenUpdater;
}

private void OnDisable()
{
    MenuOpenUpdater = false;
}

private void OnEnable()
{
    MenuOpenUpdater = true;
}
```

This would be the main script (GameMenu), the one that I want to have the onEnable() and the onDisable() but that executes with the object containing the secondary script, so I can only use this one.

```
void Start(){
    private bool MenuOpen;
}

void Update()
{
    MenuOpen = MenuOpenUpdate.MenuOpenUpdater;
}
```

}

As you can see, the secondary script changes a bool value depending if it's active or disabled, and then sends the value to the main script. The result I'm expecting is to have this on a single script by detecting when the child object gets enabled or disabled from the parent object script.

I don't know if this is possible and it's just a matter of making it more simple, if it can't be done I can stick to using multiple scripts for this, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you literally only want to query whether the object is active, you could use the [ActiveInHierarchy](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-activeInHierarchy.html) property and check that in your main script.
2. You can create a custom component that you can add to all your sub-elements. This would include your inner script and any custom behaviour you need, but you could name it ObjectEnabler or whatever and attach it to all your elements. Then in your main script you can refer to variable of referenced objects.
3. An event-driven approach would be to modify the inner script to have an event you can subscribe to:

Inner object:

```
public EventHandler event ObjectEnabled;
void OnEnabled()
{
    ObjectEnabled?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
}
```

And the outer to subscribe to it:

```
InnerObjectReference.ObjectEnabled += InnerObjectEnabledHandler;

public void InnerObjectEnabledHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: The solution was using gameObject.activeInHierarchy in order to know if the object was active or not. Thank you very much for your answer, the explanation helped me a lot.